# Tensorflow MNIST accuracy not calculated correctly

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I'm just starting out with tensorflow and I'm trying to classify the images from the MNIST dataset using a NN with 2 hidden and one output layer with a softmax function. Im optimizing with minibatch gd and tracking the accuracy on the last minibatch after each epoch.

```
def fetch_batch(batch_index, batch_size, data=train_data, labels=train_labels):
    low_ind = batch_index*batch_size
    upp_ind = (batch_index+1)*batch_size
    if upp_ind < data.shape[0]:
        return data[low_ind:upp_ind], labels[low_ind:upp_ind]
    else:
        return data[low_ind:], labels[low_ind:]

n_inputs = 28*28 # MNIST image size
n_hidden_1 = 300
n_hidden_2 = 100
n_outputs = 10 # ten different classes

learning_rate = 0.01

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, n_inputs), name="X")
y = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, shape=(None), name="y")

with tf.name_scope("dnn"):
    hidden_1 = tf.layers.dense(X, n_hidden_1, name="hidden_1", activation=tf.nn.relu)
    hidden_2 = tf.layers.dense(hidden_1, n_hidden_2, name="hidden_2", activation=tf.nn.relu)
    logits = tf.layers.dense(hidden_2, n_outputs, name="outputs")

with tf.name_scope("loss"):
    xentropy = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y, logits=logits)
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(xentropy, name="loss")

with tf.name_scope("train"):
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate)
    training_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)

with tf.name_scope("eval"):
    correct = tf.nn.in_top_k(logits, y, 1)
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, tf.float32))

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
saver = tf.train.Saver()

batch_size = 50
n_epochs = 50
m = train_data.shape[0]

with tf.Session() as sess:
    init.run()
    for epoch in range(n_epochs):
        for batch_index in range(m//batch_size):
            X_minibatch, y_minibatch = fetch_batch(batch_index, batch_size)
            #X_batch, y_batch = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
            sess.run(training_op, feed_dict={X: X_minibatch, y: y_minibatch})
        acc_train = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={X: X_minibatch, y: y_minibatch})
        acc_val = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={X: mnist.validation.images, y: mnist.validation.labels})
        print(epoch, "Train accuracy: ", acc_train, " Val accuracy: ", acc_val)
```

When running using the MNIST helper for training I get the right accuracies (the one I used for validation accuracy), however I'd like to know why my own implementation doesn't work as it always outputs an accuracy of 0.0. The minibatches shapes from my data and the one from the tensorflow helper are the same. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to normalize your data, e.g.

```
train_data = train_data / 255.0
validation_data = validation_data / 255.0
```

If you google "*Why should I normalize data in Machine Learning*" you will find out  why it is important.

Comment: Hey, thank you, that actually was the solution. But why was the accuracy always 0.0 in the beginning? Shouldn't it at least be around ~10% due to "random" guessing even with the slow training with missing normalization (I also tried larger minibatches, so the guessing wasn't just very unlucky)?

Comment: It's probably because test data size is relatively small and for each label you have `1/100` (corrected from `1/10` since both labels and logits must have the same value) probability of being selected which is not enough. If you would use train data (60000 samples - put the whole data) for validation I think you should get something `> 0`.

Comment: I think 1/10 was correct, as the labels are fixed and we have a 1/10 chance of the highest logit's index being the label on each example. I tried to put the whole training data to evaluate accuracy and got (as expected by this chance) 10% accuracy on the first few epochs, then the accuracy went to 0 again.

Comment: If you take a single label, say `y=0`, and apply it to the whole dataset, then you will have a fixed label and you will be correct. Otherwise, for each data point `x`  label `y` can be in range `0-9`. So we have `P(y=y')*P(argmax(softmax(logits))=y')=(1/10)*(1/10)`, justifiably assuming that `y` and `logits` are independent events and that for each event in both `logits` and `labels` there is an equal probability to be generated.